# How are these lines of swift code different?

Tags: swift

```
let fakeDataSource = FakeDataSource()

tableView?.dataSource = fakeDataSource
```

versus just invoking it directly with:

```
tableView?.dataSource = FakeDataSource()
```

The second example crashes with an NSException but the first example compiles and works.  I'm having trouble seeing the difference.  If you need more code pasted please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are a problem but the first may work better, briefly.

`UITableView dataSource` is a `weak` property. So unless something else has a strong reference to the data source object, the data source will become `nil`.

In the first set of code, the `FakeDataSource` instance is being held onto by the `fakeDataSource` variable. So the `FakeDataSource` instance will survive until the `fakeDataSource` variable goes out of scope.

In the second set of code, the `FakeDataSource` is created and assigned in one line. After that line, there is no longer any strong reference to the `FakeDataSource` instance so it gets deallocated right there and the `dataSource` becomes `nil` nearly immediately.

In both cases, there is a problem. The only difference is the timing of when the `FakeDataSource` instance gets deallocated.

The fix is the same for both. Keep a strong reference to the `FakeDataSource` instance. This is typically done by using a property.

Comment: This helps in better understanding deallocation when ARC is in play.  Much obliged!  How did you know UITableView dataSource is a weak property?

Comment: I know by looking at its documentation: `weak var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource? { get set }`.